# A tool for monitoring changes in region of the screen

Tags: screen, logging, monitoring

I'd like to monitoring changes in a region of a window, this windows is showing a virtual box machine, and I need to get a log with a timestamp of that changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just touch/transfer a file somewhere using ssh?

But to answer your question something like this using [`sikula`](http://sikuli.org):

- http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#creating-a-region-setting-and-getting-attributes

By creating a region object and then monitoring it, you could potentially automate by using screen capture.

- http://sikuli.wikispaces.com/Real+Use+Examples